# In Postgres, a more performant way of retrieving a session level setting

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres, the following command will return a setting value:

```
SELECT current_setting('foo');
```

If the setting doesn't exist, it will throw an exception.

We have a case where a setting may or may not exist, so we have had to create a function that catches the exception and returns null:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_foo() 
RETURNS varchar 
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN

RETURN (SELECT current_setting('foo'));

EXCEPTION 
WHEN others THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;
```

However, this performs terribly when the setting doesn't exist, presumably because throwing and catching an exception is expensive.

Is there a way to check if the setting exists?

Answer (score 3):

There are actually two functions named `current_setting`. The first, which you've used accepts a single `string` representing the variable name. The other, accepts two arguments, a `string` for the variable name and a `boolean` indicating whether the missing variable name is okay.

Just use `SELECT coalesce(current_setting('my.foo', true), 'mydefault');`

example:

```
postgres=> set session my.foo to 'baz';
SET
postgres=> select current_setting('public.foo', true);
 current_setting 
-----------------
 baz
(1 row)
postgres=> select current_setting('public.bar', true);
 current_setting 
-----------------
 
(1 row)
postgres=> select coalesce(current_setting('public.bar', true), 'mydefault');
 coalesce  
-----------
 mydefault
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this system view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-settings.html) instead of `current_setting` function.

```
SELECT setting FROM pg_catalog.pg_settings WHERE name = 'foo';
```

Another "bonus" is you can use it as a regular table:

```
(filip@[local]:5432) filip=# SELECT name, setting, unit, source, boot_val FROM pg_settings WHERE name ~ 'mem';
            name            | setting | unit |       source       | boot_val 
----------------------------+---------+------+--------------------+----------
 autovacuum_work_mem        | -1      | kB   | default            | -1
 dynamic_shared_memory_type | posix   | NULL | configuration file | posix
 hash_mem_multiplier        | 1       | NULL | default            | 1
 logical_decoding_work_mem  | 65536   | kB   | default            | 65536
 maintenance_work_mem       | 512000  | kB   | session            | 65536
 shared_memory_type         | mmap    | NULL | default            | mmap
 work_mem                   | 20480   | kB   | session            | 4096
(7 rows)


(filip@[local]:5432) filip=# SELECT source, count(*) FROM pg_settings GROUP BY 1;
        source        | count 
----------------------+-------
 client               |     2
 environment variable |     1
 configuration file   |    26
 default              |   291
 session              |     2
 override             |    13
(6 rows)
```